# Exporting data from SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

i am using DTSWizard to export my data on local database to Database server.

Initially when i tried to first execute the create scripts of tables and then tried to export data then the Id's of all the data is changed and hence the data become garbage for me.

Then i tried to export data directly without using the create script for tables. It works fine and the id's remain the same. 
But the problem is that the tables having Identity field are not set and i have to manually set the identity constraint of the table.

My database has around 254 tables and its hard to modify every table to set identity constraint

Please help me if there is any way through which i can export data without disturbing the Id's and also the identity property of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the Microsoft Migration Assistent to do this ?

Edit:
Sorry, missed the point is was server-to-server. I think your best bet is to use SQL Server Management Studio, backup the database and restore it on the other server.

Comment: @pritaeas : i dont have any idea of this. can u please tell me how to use it

Comment: but i dont know how to restore database from remote computer as 1 is database server and backup is at my local computer

Comment: Can't you remote access your database server ?

Comment: i can access but when trying to restore database, it ask path of local file system i.e. database servers file system so i dont know that how to use bakup kept on my computers file system

Comment: Upload the backup file to the server.

Comment: but for that i dont have permission

Comment: No remote desktop or ftp access ?

Comment: i do have ftp account but i cant browse that through SQL Management Studio